# Eclipse Android Project forces close immediately after startup?

Tags: java, android

I am coding an accelerometer app for android through Eclipse. I am new to programming Java (this is my fourth app). When running the app it opens but textview1 doesn't even display before the app crashes and my device returns to its home screen. Any thoughts?! I researched but everyone else's problems are different than mine (problems included: abstract class, 
 in the xml, and some others).

Attached is my MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml, and my manifest.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.accelerometer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    float [] history = new float[3];
    private int mIndex = 0;
    private int[] mImgs = new int[3];

    public Bitmap mBitMap;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView mImage;

    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer;
    private long lastUpdate = 0;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 600;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImgs[0] = R.drawable.left;
        mImgs[1] = R.drawable.right;
        mImgs[2] = R.drawable.up;
        mImgs[3] = R.drawable.down;
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//      mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[mIndex]);
        mImage.setImageResource(mImgs[mIndex]);  // Easiest way to show a image

        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float xChange = history[0] - event.values[0];
            float yChange = history[1] - event.values[1];
            float zChange = history[2] - event.values[2];

            history[0] = event.values[0];
            history[1] = event.values[1];
            history[2] = event.values[2];

            if ((Math.abs(xChange) > 2) || (Math.abs(yChange) > 2) || (Math.abs(zChange) > 2))
            {
                if ((xChange > yChange) && (xChange > zChange))

                {

                    if (xChange > 2){
                        //Left
        //              mIndex++;
        //              if (mIndex == 3) { mIndex = 0; }  // Overflow
                        mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[0]);
                        mImage.setImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (xChange < -2){
                        //Right
                        mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[1]);
                        mImage.setImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                if ((yChange > xChange) && (yChange > zChange))

                    if (yChange > 2)
                    {
                        //Down
                        mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[2]);
                        mImage.setImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (yChange < -2){
                        //Up
                        mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[3]);
                        mImage.setImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
            }
            if ((zChange > xChange) && (zChange > yChange))
            {
            if (zChange > 2){
                //Out
                mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[0]);
                mImage.setImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (zChange < -2){
                //In
                mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgs[0]);
                mImage.setImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            }
        }

//          
//              
//              float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;
//              
//              if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
//   
//              }
//   
//              last_x = x;
//              last_y = y;
//              last_z = z;

            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/up"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.accelerometer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accelerometer.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Comment: Did you try using the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm sure you're getting an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)(there may be a few more problems though).

```
private int[] mImgs = new int[3]; // mImgs is an array of 3 elements
```

When you declare an array like this, the maximum possible index for this 2 and thus only `mImgs[2]`  is accessible (i.e) the `array.length - 1`.

But in your `onCreate()` method, you have a snippet like this

```
    mImgs[0] = R.drawable.left; // first element
    mImgs[1] = R.drawable.right; // second
    mImgs[2] = R.drawable.up; // third and final possible element of the array
    mImgs[3] = R.drawable.down; // this throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as mImgs[3] is not a valid index for an array of size 3
```

Comment: I fixed that before and it didn't work for me, but then I changed it again after I uploaded this and it worked-- strange!

Comment: @user3416852 - Probably you wouldn't have cleaned your project then and this time, after making this change, a fresh clean build would have happened. It happens a lot of time with everybody :)